# Searching with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, search, performance

I have a collection of objects, each with an int Frame property. Given an int, I want to find the object in the collection that has the closest Frame.

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
public static void Search(int frameNumber)
{
    var differences = (from rec in _records
                       select new { FrameDiff = Math.Abs(rec.Frame - frameNumber), Record = rec }).OrderBy(x => x.FrameDiff);

    var closestRecord = differences.FirstOrDefault().Record;

    //continue work...
}
```

This is great and everything, except there are 200,000 items in my collection and I call this method very frequently. Is there a relatively easy, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: is this just LINQ to a collection of objects or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: "I have a collection of Objects", first sentence in the question. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var closestRecord = _records.MinBy(rec => Math.Abs(rec.Frame - frameNumber));
```

using MinBy from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Answer (score 3):

What you might want to try is to store the frames in a datastructure that's sorted by `Frame`. Then you can do a binary search when you need to find the closest one to a given frameNumber.

Comment: Perhaps look into the SortedList collection as your data structure.

Comment: Isn't the point to do it in linq? How would this be linq? Code example?

Comment: I would be ok with a solution that doesn't use linq. I'm just looking for "simple."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I would use LINQ for this, at least not with an orderby.

```
static Record FindClosestRecord(IEnumerable<Record> records, int number)
{
    Record closest = null;
    int leastDifference = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (Record record in records)
    {
        int difference = Math.Abs(number - record.Frame);
        if (difference == 0)
        {
            return record; // exact match, return early
        }
        else if (difference < leastDifference)
        {
            leastDifference = difference;
            closest = record;
        }
    }

    return closest;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how MoreLINQ's `MinBy` method -- as suggested in dtb's answer -- works. (Although `MinBy` can't special-case the early exit for an exact match.)

Comment: If you have a sorted collection, you can have an even better early exit. Plus if you use a "for" loop, you can remember the last used index and start the search from there rather than from the beginning of the collection. Good balance between simple and fast. That's what I ultimately chose to do, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine your statements into one ala:

```
var closestRecord = (from rec in _records
                   select new { FrameDiff = Math.Abs(rec.Frame - frameNumber), 
                   Record = rec }).OrderBy(x => x.FrameDiff).FirstOrDefault().Record;
```

Comment: I believe that his problem is that sort (which is actually not needed) is taking very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could divide your big itemlist in 5 - 10 smaller lists that are ordered by their Framediff or something ?

this way the search is faster if you know in which list you need to search